# How to get data from api using http request with body or raw data as parameter in Flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart, parameters

curl --location --request GET 'My_API?' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--data-raw '[
{
"id": "",
"placeid":
"EiBMZXdpc2hhbSBXYXksIExvbmRvbiBTRTQgMVVZLCBVSyIuKiwKFAoSCXk1YsdYAnZIERCJXqRiE8WPEhQKEgnrjwApXwJ2SBH76fXJO6C02w",
"address": "Lewisham Way, London SE4 1UY, UK",
"postcode": "SE4 1UY",
"outcode": "SE4 1UY",
"lattitude": 51.4702816,
"country": "United Kingdom",
"city": "Greater London",
"longitude": -0.029187800000045172
},
{
"_id": "null",
"placeid": "",
"address": "Kenley Road, London SW19 3DW, UK",
"postcode": "SE23 3RF",
"outcode": "SE23",
"lattitude": "51.404556",
"country": "",
"city": "",
"longitude": "-0.194486"
}
**I want to fetch distance between these points. it is working fine in Postman but not working in Flutter.**
***Flutter Code***

var req = await Requests.post('my_api?', headers: {
'Content-Type' :  'application/json'
}, body: queryParameters);
print('response_____________O______________)__________*********0___________O*********\n');
print(req.json());
print(req.content().length);

Comment: elaborate your issue

Comment: i want to fetch data from api passing list of object two as parameter in http request . when I'm passing these objects post man as body it is working fine but not working in flutter.

Comment: post your question in proper format cant understand anything

Comment: https://medium.com/@maffan/how-to-fetch-data-using-api-calls-in-flutter-99668a60170c check this

Comment: Can you share photo of postman?

Answer (score 0):

Have you check https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json? You could put all these data in a class defined for.

Comment: yes I have visited but can't find my answer.

Comment: Doesn't it work if you defined a big class with all the element in your raw data?